# Creating table does not reflect in DynamoDB console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have following code written in DynamoDB for table creation. I am running this with Eclise. I have configured Tomcat server. I deployed my app on Tomcat and open the localhost URL.

```
DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(dynamo);
ArrayList<AttributeDefinition> attributeDefinitions = new ArrayList<AttributeDefinition>();
attributeDefinitions.add(new AttributeDefinition()
        .withAttributeName("Id").withAttributeType("N"));

ArrayList<KeySchemaElement> keySchema = new ArrayList<KeySchemaElement>();
keySchema.add(new KeySchemaElement().withAttributeName("Id")
        .withKeyType(KeyType.HASH));

CreateTableRequest request1 = new CreateTableRequest()
        .withTableName("abcdef")
        .withKeySchema(keySchema)
        .withAttributeDefinitions(attributeDefinitions)
        .withProvisionedThroughput(new ProvisionedThroughput()
            .withReadCapacityUnits(5L)
            .withWriteCapacityUnits(6L));

System.out.println("Issuing CreateTable request for abcde");
Table table = dynamoDB.createTable(request1);

System.out.println("Waiting for abcde to be created...this may take a while...");
table.waitForActive();
```

It runs successfully. It also shows the table created successfully. 
But when I open Amazon DynamoDB console, it does not reflect the newly created table. Can anyone suggest me what goes wrong here ? I have properly configured secretKey and accessKey.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could it be a different region where the tables created and the console shows?

Comment: Is there anyway I can check the location in both Eclipse and dynamoDB console ?

Comment: You are right. I can view the table in region=us-east-1